# NSFetchedResultsController: Two sort descriptors with the same key not working. One descending for sections, the other ascending for rows

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I use a NSFetchedResultsController for populating a TableView. I want the sections to be sorted descending by date and the rows sorted ascending by date. Both use the key 'creation'  and the sections have a transient property for the sectionNameKeyPath which returns a string for the date with the form: "Today, Yesterday, 20.11.2013, 19.11.2013, …" created from the 'creation' date. However, the rows are *always* sorted in the ordering of the first sort descriptor. Is this approach wrong?

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Exercise"];
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creation" ascending:NO],
                            [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creation" ascending:YES]];

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.context
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"localizedCreationDate"
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

I am grateful for any provided help!
br

**UPDATE**

The above approach can't work. :) I solved it by saving a second date as a property with the beginning of the day, ordered descending. This is also used as the sectionNameKeyPath. Additionally, for section header titles the localizedCreationDate is used.

```
- (void)setuptFetchedResultsController
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"DNALoggedExercise"];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDayDate" ascending:NO],
                                [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.context
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"creationDayDate"
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first piece of code, you're giving two contradictory `NSSortDescriptors`, so only one is considered, and probably the first.

By creating a second date property just for convenience, you're introducing data duplication in your database, that's not a very good idea.
Why not sorting your results in whichever order, and just reading the array in reverse in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `titleForHeaderInSection` ? Even better, why not having a small private method in your viewController that would prepare a NSDictionary or any other convenience data structure for later use?

Comment: I already tried the approach and ran into some problems when inserting/deleting rows. Everything went as expected, except the TableVIew was not populated when ervery row was deleted and one entity added again. But you are right. It's better than data duplication and i will try again and report the results back. :)